# Is there any connection between Vishnu and Rudra in Rigveda?

Tags: vishnu, shiva, rig-veda

Does the two deities ever interact or ever mentioned together anywhere in Rigveda?

Comment: what is this newfound obsession with *Rig Veda*?. Vedas were one large corpus that were divided around 5000 years ago by Ved Vyasa. Vyasa literally means to divide. The idea that one Veda came first and others came later is wrong. It's like saying chapter 1 of a book is 'older' than chapter 2.

Answer (score 4):

They don't interact (like Vishnu interacts with Indra in a subordinate role).  But they are mentioned together occasionally:

One verse says:

> “asya devasya mīḷhuṣo vayā viṣṇoreṣasya prabhṛthe havirbhiḥ | vide hi
> rudro rudriyaṃ mahitvaṃ yāsiṣṭaṃ vartiraśvināvirāvat |” (Rig Veda
> 7.40.5)
>
> “With offerings I propitiate the branches of this swift-moving God,
> the bounteous Viṣṇu. Hence Rudra gained his Rudra-strength“.

Modern translations like Brererton and Jamison convey an almost opposite sense from older translations like Griffith's:

> There is propitiation for this god who grants rewards [=Rudra], at the ritual offering to quick Viṣṇu, with oblations,for Rudra knows his own Rudrian might. A
> śvins, drive your circuit of refreshment

There is a dual divinity Soma-Rudra

http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rigveda/rv06074.htm

and Soma is called the father of Vishnu in 9 96 5

https://en.wikisource.org/wiki/The_Rig_Veda/Mandala_9/Hymn_96

> "Father of holy hymns, Soma flows onward the Father of the earth,
> Father of heaven:  Father of Agni, Surya's generator, the Father who
> begat Indra and Visnu."

Comment: Stack Exchange uses Markdown to format posts. Please format your posts properly. [How do I format my posts using Markdown or HTML?](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/help/formatting).